# Is it correct to say "Item was succesfully rejected"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, redundancy

In a web application we need to give a success message to a user saying that the action of rejecting the selected item has been succesful.

In this context, is it correct to use the message:

> Item was successfully rejected.

or would:

> Item was rejected.

suffice?

**Note:**
I tend to go with the former one, considering the fact that a rejection process can be both success and failure.

Comment: 'Item was rejected as requested' sounds less comical.

Comment: The problem is that the first message gives the impression that you are not serious and are perhaps poking fun at the user.

Comment: So, is there a message "Item was unsuccessfully rejected." or "Item failed to be rejected." if for some reason the action didn't go through?

Comment: @thomj1332 _Item was unsuccessfully rejected._ - Nope, that sounds awkward even to me; _Item failed to be rejected._ - Yes there is, it is something on the lines of: **An error occurred while rejecting the item**.

Answer (score 1):

"Item was successfully rejected" carries the added connotation that this is what you wanted. You shouldn't be surprised by this result. You're the one requesting the rejection.

"Item was rejected" might be someone/something else doing the rejecting.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Item was successfully rejected" works quite well in this context, and I would avoid using "Item was rejected."  If you use "Item was successfully rejected" there is less ambiguity that the rejection was the item the user was attempting to reject, not the action of trying to reject that was rejected (wow that sounds confusing!!)  In other words, "Item was successfully rejected" makes it less ambiguous to your user that their action was successful rather than some error occurring with the system that resulted in their action being rejected.

Comment: CandiedOrange has already said this.

Comment: If that's what CandiedOrange intended to say, @EdwinAshworth. it certainly wasn't clear to me.  That response seemed to imply someone else, rather than a system, was doing to the rejecting.  My answer should provide greater clarity.  In addition, the other answer did not take the OP's original question context into account.